# Magento2.4: How to get the language pack content only for frontend?

Tags: magento2, multi-website, language-package

I have imported the French language pack on our website.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-extensions/language-packs.html

But the CSV file contains the language changes for both frontend and backend. Is it possible to get the language pack only for frontend?

Comment: you mean to display the translations only on frontend and not on backend? or to include only the translations for frontend stuff in the language pack itself?

Comment: in the language pack itself

Answer (score 1):

When language packs are generated, usually the command used is  `bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases` which will extract all translatable words and phrases it can find within the path you provide for it to crawl. It doesn't know about frontend/ admin scopes.

More details here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html